# Recurse XML file using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am trying to use recursive technique to retrieve xml file. Can somebody help me doing that.

I am trying to read below xml, but not sure the depth of the nested tags, so i thought of using recursive technique.

```
<TestSuites>
  <TestSuite SuiteName="Regression">
    <TestCase TCName="TestCase 1">
      <TestStep TSName="TestStep 1"/>
      <TestStep TSName="TestStep 2"/>
    </TestCase>
    <TestCase TCName="TestCase 2">
      <TestStep TSName="TestStep 1"/>
      <TestStep TSName="TestStep 2"/>
    </TestCase>
  </TestSuite>
  <TestSuite SuiteName="Smoke"/>
  <TestSuite SuiteName="Sanity"/>
</TestSuites>
```

Comment: Rather: what are you trying to achieve? You have to provide far more details before anyone could make an even halfway educated guess.

Comment: I am trying to read below xml, but not sure the depth of the nested tags, so i thought of using recursive technique  <TestSuites><TestSuite SuiteName="Regression"><TestCase TCName="TestCase 1"><TestStep TSName="TestStep 1"/><TestStep TSName="TestStep 2"/></TestCase><TestCase TCName="TestCase 2"><TestStep TSName="TestStep 1"/><TestStep TSName="TestStep 2"/></TestCase></TestSuite><TestSuite SuiteName="Smoke"/><TestSuite SuiteName="Sanity"/></TestSuites>

Comment: I took the liberty of updating your question with the text from your comment. Please avoid posting code fragments in comments, because they tend to be hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript provides you with [tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to parse and process XML structures:

```
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.load "c:\path\to\foo.xml"
WScript.Echo xml.xml
```

You can access elements in the document tree using (among other things) the [XPath](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) query language:

```
Set nodes = xml.selectnodes("//TestStep[@TSName='TestStep 2']")
```

The above selects all `TestStep` nodes anywhere in the tree, which have an attribute `TSName` with a value `TestStep 2`.

Once you have the node(s) you can read or change their attributes:

```
WScript.Echo nodes.Length
WScript.Echo nodes(0).parentNode.nodeName
WScript.Echo nodes(1).parentNode.nodeName

WScript.Echo nodes(0).text
nodes(0).text = "foo"
WScript.Echo nodes(0).text
WScript.Echo xml.xml
```

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner "Pass by value", actually. ;) Those who don't know what we're talking about: allow me to refer you to [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) on this matter.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment (asking for the removal of the param list () in the .load statement) @Ansgar referes to.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive Sub to traverse the XML document tree. In principle:

```
  Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\so14975608.xml")
  Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  oXML.load sFSpec
  If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
     recursiveTraversal oXML.documentElement, 0
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If

Sub recursiveTraversal(oElm, nIndent)
  WScript.Echo Space(nIndent), oElm.tagName
  If 0 < oElm.childNodes.length Then
     Dim oChild
     For Each oChild In oElm.childNodes
         recursiveTraversal oChild, nIndent + 2
     Next
  Else
     If 0 < oElm.attributes.length Then
        Dim oAttr
        For Each oAttr In oElm.attributes
            WScript.Echo Space(nIndent + 1), oAttr.name, oAttr.value
        Next
     End If
  End If
End Sub
```

output for your sample data:

```
 TestSuites
   TestSuite
     TestCase
       TestStep
        TSName TestStep 1
       TestStep
        TSName TestStep 2
     TestCase
       TestStep
        TSName TestStep 1
       TestStep
        TSName TestStep 2
   TestSuite
    SuiteName Smoke
   TestSuite
    SuiteName Sanity
```

Based on a more detailed plan - what information do you need to extract/process - you must study some suitable XML documentation [(start here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine the functions/properties to put in the above skeleton.

**P.S.:**

People who did not buy the above won't profit from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15219548/603855).