# How can I extract all child nodes with a common text value

Tags: xml, vbscript

Given the following XML

```
<Tests>
    <AutomatedTests>
        <TestName>Test1</TestName>
        <FunctionalLibraries>
            <FunctionalLibrary>CommonLib</FunctionalLibrary>
            <FunctionalLibrary>AppTestLib</FunctionalLibrary>
            <FunctionalLibrary>Test1Lib</FunctionalLibrary>
        </FunctionalLibraries>
    </AutomatedTests>
    <AutomatedTests>
        <TestName>Test2</TestName>
        <FunctionalLibraries>
            <FunctionalLibrary>CommonLib</FunctionalLibrary>
            <FunctionalLibrary>AppTestLib</FunctionalLibrary>
            <FunctionalLibrary>Test2Lib</FunctionalLibrary>
        </FunctionalLibraries>
    </AutomatedTests>
    <AutomatedTests>
        <TestName>Test3</TestName>
        <FunctionalLibraries>
            <FunctionalLibrary>CommonLib</FunctionalLibrary>
            <FunctionalLibrary>Test3Lib</FunctionalLibrary>
        </FunctionalLibraries>
    </AutomatedTests>
</Tests>
```

Using VBScript, how can I find all the /Tests/AutomatedTests/FunctionalLibraries nodes that are common to ALL the /Tests/AutomatedTests nodes.
Based on the above xml, the results should be...

```
<CommonTestLibraries>
    <FunctionalLibrary>CommonLib</FunctionalLibrary>
</CommonTestLibraries>
```

Thanks

Here is what I have, I am hoping there is a simpler way since I have to do this several times on the same file.

```
set tempDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
set commonDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Load(fileName)
set testNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Tests/AutomatedTests")
isFirst = true

for each testNode in testNodes
    set functionalLibraryNodes = testNode.SelectNodes("FunctionLibraries/FunctionLibrary")
    For Each functionalLibraryNode in functionalLibraryNodes
       If not tempDict.Exists(functionalLibraryNode.Text) Then
            tempDict.Add functionalLibraryNode.Text, functionalLibraryNode.Text
       End If
    Next
    If NOT isFirst Then
        for each item in commonDict
            if tempDict.Exists(item) = false Then
                commonDict.Remove item
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Set commonDict = tempDict
        isFirst = false
    End If

    Set tempDict = nothing
    Set tempDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Next
```

Comment: Have you looked here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975608/recurse-xml-file-using-vbscript

Comment: SO is not a "write code for me free" type of site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Leptonator, the link you suggested does not appear to satisfy my requirements.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I did not ask to have any code written, just a suggestion on the best way to solve a problem.  But to answer your question, I have edited my post with code that I am using

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this:

```vbs
filename = "C:\path\to\your.xml"

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.load filename

If xmlDoc.parseError <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo xmlDoc.parseError.reason
  WScript.Quit xmlDoc.parseError
End If

'determine the total number of tests
numTests = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Tests/AutomatedTests").length

'count the libraries from all tests
Set commonDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each node In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//FunctionalLibrary")
  commonDict(node.text) = commonDict(node.text) + 1
Next

'libraries common to all tests must have occurred {numTests} number of times
For Each lib In commonDict.Keys
  If commonDict(lib) = numTests Then WScript.Echo commonDict(lib)
Next
```

There may be more efficient ways, though.

**Note:** the line

```
commonDict(node.text) = commonDict(node.text) + 1
```

makes use of the fact that an expression `dict(key)` automatically adds a non-existing key to the dictionary and initializes it with an empty value. That empty value is then cast to 0 in the addition. Explicit code with the same semantic would look like this:

```vbs
If Not commonDict.Exists(node.text) Then
  commonDict(node.text) = 0
Else
  commonDict(node.text) = commonDict(node.text) + 1
End If
```

**Note:** The XPath expression `//FunctionalLibrary` will select `FunctionalLibrary` nodes from anywhere in the XML tree. If you have any such nodes that are *not* immediate child nodes of `/Tests/AutomatedTests/FunctionalLibraries` (the sample data you provided suggests you don't), you should make the XPath expression explicit:

```vbs
funclib = "/Tests/AutomatedTests/FunctionalLibraries/FunctionalLibrary"
For Each node In xmlDoc.selectNodes(funclib)
  commonDict(node.text) = commonDict(node.text) + 1
Next
```

Comment: nice, +1; but `WScript.Quit xmlDoc.parseError` should use `WScript.Quit xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode` or a suitable constant, and I think that "//FunctionalLibrary" - as all XPathes starting with "//" - is risky.

Comment: `errorCode` is the default property of the `parseError` object, so `xmlDoc.parseError` and `xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode` are the same. As for using `//` in the XPath query: yes, that query might yield bogus results when the XML contains `FunctionalLibrary` nodes that are not immediate child nodes of `/Tests/AutomatedTests/FunctionalLibraries`. However, the sample data doesn't suggest this being the case. I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: I do like this approach.  Using only the one dictionary makes things easier to manage.  And as for the 'Adding a non-existent key' note, I was not aware of this, Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

As a 'common' lib occurs n times in n tests, the dictionary approach can be much simpler:

```
  Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\02.xml")
  Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  oXML.load sFSpec
  If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
     Dim sXPath : sXPath     = "/Tests/AutomatedTests/FunctionalLibraries/FunctionalLibrary"
     Dim ndlFnd : Set ndlFnd = oXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
     If 0 = ndlFnd.length Then
        WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
     Else
        Dim dicLibs  : Set dicLibs  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim nTests   : nTests       = ndlFnd(0).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes.length
        WScript.Echo nTests, "tests"
        Dim ndFnd, sLib
        For Each ndFnd In ndlFnd
            sLib  = ndFnd.text
            dicLibs(sLib) = dicLibs(sLib) + 1
        Next
        For Each sLib In dicLibs.Keys()
            If dicLibs(sLib) = nTests Then
               WScript.Echo sLib, dicLibs(sLib)
            End If
        Next
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```