# VBScript : How to iterate dynamically to subnodes of xml file using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a xml file with a root node which has child node and that child node may have it's own child node which in turn have other child node and so on. like child1 is child of parent and child2 is child of child1 and so on

structure as follows

```
<parent>
    <child1>
        <child2>
            <child3>
            </child3>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

The problem is that I don't know the level of nesting of nodes i.e. number of child nodes within one child node
I want to dynamically read the nodes from xml file

Currently I am using this vbscript code

```
set x=xmlDoc.documentElement
 msgbox "Nodename: " & x.nodeName & vbNewLine 
set y=x.childNodes

for i=0 to y.length-1
 msgbox "Nodename: " & y(i).nodeName & vbNewLine 

 for z=0 to y(i).childNodes.length-1
   msgbox "Nodename: " & y(i).childNodes(z).nodeName & vbNewLine
 next
next
```

But for this the level of nesting is required to know in advance and accordingly the number of loop is required.
Example:Above code can read upto child1 for reading child2, It requires to add one more loop and so for child3 one more loop is required. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want a recursive function that accepts a `IXMLDOMNodeList` as it's input, whenever `IXMLDOMNodeNode.hasChildNodes() = True` call the recursive function again this time passing the `ChildNodes` `IXMLDOMNodeList` as the input.

Comment: An example of how to recursively iterate through an XML document can be found here [Recurse XML file using vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14987356/692942).

Comment: How did you get on salam, did the suggestions help?

Comment: Yes,It helped.I got the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from my comments above, you want a simple [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) something like below should give you a starting point.

```vb
Dim xml: xml = "<parent><child1><child2><child3></child3></child2></child1></parent>"
Dim xmldoc : Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

If xmldoc.LoadXML(xml) Then
  Call MapNodes(xmldoc)
End If

'Recursive sub procedure that takes a Node as input.
Sub MapNodes(CurrentNode)
  Dim Node

  If IsObject(CurrentNode) Then
    If CurrentNode.HasChildNodes() Then
      For Each Node In CurrentNode.childNodes
        WScript.Echo "<" & Node.nodeName & ">"
        'Do we have ChildNodes? Call the procedure again this time
        'passing the Node we are currently checking.
        If Node.HasChildNodes() Then Call MapNodes(Node)
        WScript.Echo "</" & Node.nodeName & ">"
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Output:

```
<parent>
<child1>
<child2>
<child3>
</child3>
</child2>
</child1>
</parent>
```