# Parsing an XML using VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have to parse and XML which has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserConfig>
<add key="key1" value="value1" />
<add key="key2" value="value2" />
</UserConfig>
```

Comment: Did you notice the "Related" column on the right side of this page? Did you do any research at all?

Comment: And what you had tried?

Comment: I tried looking up for a few parsing solutions. Couldn't find anything related to the kind of xml I am looking to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started I combined the two answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14975608/603855):

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".\44567515.xml")
Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
oXML.load sFSpec
If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
   recursiveTraversal oXML.documentElement, 0
   WScript.Echo "------------"
   Dim sXPath : sXPath = "//add[@key='key2']"
   Dim nodes  : Set nodes = oXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
   If 0 = nodes.length Then
      WScript.Echo "no nodes for", sXPath
   Else
     WScript.Echo nodes(0).nodeName
     WScript.Echo nodes(0).getAttribute("value")
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
End If

Sub recursiveTraversal(oElm, nIndent)
WScript.Echo Space(nIndent), oElm.tagName
If 0 < oElm.childNodes.length Then
   Dim oChild
   For Each oChild In oElm.childNodes
       recursiveTraversal oChild, nIndent + 2
   Next
Else
   If 0 < oElm.attributes.length Then
      Dim oAttr
      For Each oAttr In oElm.attributes
          WScript.Echo Space(nIndent + 1), oAttr.name, oAttr.value
      Next
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

Output:

```
cscript 44567515.vbs
 UserConfig
   add
    key key1
    value value1
   add
    key key2
    value value2
------------
add
value2
```

Comment: Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner - that helped. Though I found out that I was just looking for the node.getAttribute() method and was not able to use it correctly - my bad. Your response was very helpful too. :)